# How can I find the average of 10 values in an array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am attempting to find the average of 10 signal strength values that have been inserted into an array periodically with the NSTimer function. I know the timer is working due to the console logs, but the array of the 10 values does not. Is there a small error in the code or potentially an issue with the if/else statement?

```
- (IBAction)getSignalAvg:(id)sender {

    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(arrayBuild)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];

}

- (void)arrayBuild {

    loopCount++;

    // Initialise Array
    NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (loopCount >= 11) {

        // Invalidate Timer
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;

        // Find Average
        NSNumber *avg = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];

        // Change Text of Label to Average & Log
        self.avgSignal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",avg];
        NSLog(@"%@",avg);



    }else{

        // Declare Signal Strength
        float signalstrength = CTGetSignalStrength();

        // Individual Result & Convert to Integer
        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", signalstrength];
        NSInteger resultInt = [result integerValue];

        // Add Object
        [resultsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:resultInt]];

        // Change Text of Label Each Second
        self.avgSignal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",loopCount];
        NSLog(@"%f",signalstrength);

    }
}
```

Comment: NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; check this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare yout resultArray in .h file because each n every time you're creating new array. That's why you're not able to do that. So please use like this

**.h File**

```
NSMutableArray *resultsArray;
```

**.m File**

```
- (IBAction)getSignalAvg:(id)sender {

    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(arrayBuild)
                                             userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            // Initialise Array
  if([resultArray count] == 0)
    resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];                                  
  else
     [resultArray removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)arrayBuild {

    loopCount++;



    if (loopCount >= 11) {

        // Invalidate Timer
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;

        // Find Average
        NSNumber *avg = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];

        // Change Text of Label to Average & Log
        self.avgSignal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",avg];
        NSLog(@"%@",avg);



    }else{

        // Declare Signal Strength
        float signalstrength = CTGetSignalStrength();

        // Individual Result & Convert to Integer
        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", signalstrength];
        NSInteger resultInt = [result integerValue];

        // Add Object
        [resultsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:resultInt]];

        // Change Text of Label Each Second
        self.avgSignal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",loopCount];
        NSLog(@"%f",signalstrength);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time the `arrayBuild` method is called you create a new `NSMutableArray` thus you will only have the one value in there.

You need to create a class instance for the `NSMutableArray` `resultsArray`. Just declare a property in the `.h` file of this class like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *resultsArray;
```

And in the `init` of the class:

```
- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And remove the `NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in `arrayBuild` and use `self.resultsArray` instate of `resultsArray`.

Comment: Of course :/ so how can I declare it in the IBAction & then add an object to it in arrayBuild?